# How do I vertically align a form element and an img link inside a div

Tags: html, css, forms, image, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a form element (search form) and an img link inside a div.  I've tried doing 'display:inline', which set them on the same line as each other, but not as intended.  I've also tried adjusting width, float, and positioning with padding or margins, all to no avail.  I placed them inside their own divs, thinking maybe that would help, but I haven't had any success with that either.  What am I doing wrong here?  I know my code probably looks horrible stylistically, but here is their container div and the code inside :

```
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(127,137,155); MARGIN: 3% auto auto; WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 60px; BORDER-TOP: 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid" id=links>
  <div style="border:0px;width:330px;display:inline;float:left; height:45px; margin-left:4%;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;"><FORM method=post name=search action=http://dummysearchaddress/search><INPUT name=searchText> <INPUT value="Knowledge Base Search" type=submit> </FORM></div>
  <div style="border:0px;width:300px;display:inline;height:55px; margin-left:3%;margin-top:20%;margin-bottom:5%;"><A href="http://dummyimg"><IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;BORDER-TOP: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: rgb(0,0,0) 1px solid;" alt="Technical Support Manual" src="file:///C:/Users/Instructor/Desktop/img/Tech_Manual_button_204%20by%2027.png"></A>     </div>
</DIV>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: have you tried placing `vertical-align: middle;` inside the `<img>` tag style?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://jsbin.com/eyuzak/edit#html,live)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the elements you would like to align vertically in a div and use `display: table-cell` and  `vertical-align: middle`, like this:

```
<div class="center" style="height:300px">
    <img ...>
    <form ...>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.center {
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
}

/* put the two elements next to each other */
.center img, .center form {
     display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Also consider putting the style definitions in a separate css block/file.

Comment: @Sooper, yes I tried that, it was aligning them strangely, I tried vertical-align:middle on one, then vertical-align:(x%) on the other to align them properly, but it only seemed to work in ie9

Comment: @Ronak, thanks for the try, but no.  I wanted the img/form to be on the same vertical level.

Comment: Thank you Parzifal,  I believe your solution works.  However, altering the container div has made it's positioning in its container div change.  I've tried repositioning by altering margins/padding but have had no luck.  It looks fine now as I've just extended the width to make it a full box, but just so I know in the future, is there any specific reason why doing this would inhibit my ability to move the div around?  Either way, thanks a load!

Comment: Yes when you specify display: table-cell, you cannot use margin anymore because the margin of a table-cell is usually calculated by the surrounding table (attributes border-spacing and border-collapse). If you would like to add a margin, surround the div with another container div and add the margin there or if applicable add padding to the parent element.